# Registration form on landing page

Tags: signup-signon, landing-page, vouchers

Do you think that in a landing page about a service for pre-ordering lunch should have a registration form or the registration should take place in another page? 
*(after a click on the button "Sign up" which leads to a "sign up" page).*

**And what about asking only for the email?**
Admitting that after signing up users will receive a voucher to order in this site. Do you think that is it better to ask to fill in a registration form or ask for the email only ?

My thought is that, maybe a  registration form, is a bit strong and could scare users. Maybe asking only for email is better, like the page say : "I don't ask you to register to a service that you don't know. Give me only your mail so I can send you the discount coupon. Then, if you want to use this voucher to make an order, you can register later, during the checkout process".

What do you think about it?

Comment: Yes!  only ask for email and nothing else if possible.  --  https://www.goodui.org/#13

Comment: I'm not against the idea of having an e-mail form on the landing page. For services such as lunch pre-ordering though (or any service), I think it is a good practice to leave the users the ability to have a preview of the service before they sign up (features review, or, in your case, menu). So, include a link to the menu so that the users can consult it and come back to the sign up form later if they are convinced.

Comment: Hey, my advice could actually fit as "gradual engagement". -- goodui.org/#22

Comment: Have you taken into account the level of trust your user has with the service at that point? (Good article here: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/commitment-levels/) What about substituting a request on the landing page with a subtle floating widget that on-boarded users and persisted as they browsed the site?

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario will attract loads of consumers and it is completely required that you should have your registration form minimal and also the users shouldn't wander in your site.

Give and get from them the options as minimal as possible so that you can attract more loyal and repeated visitors.

Sending a voucher through mail and later making them registering seems like making the user travel much before makes an order. You better can load the user with a few points on registering which he can use while checking out. There are less possibilities for ghost orders(pranks, invalid) since you make them pay beforehand.

Mail Id and password are more than enough for registration or maybe a name for the user (which you can get while receiving the delivery address too and can store it). Since the information that you are receiving from the user is extremely minimal(with just two or three fields), you can show them the sign up form in the landing page itself.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Registration may take place on another page and that will be fine, if this is well-thought and supporting organizational objectives.

**Detailed Response:**

What is a landing page?

> A landing page is the page within a website which is meant to receive
>   your visitor directly and entices him to do something further. Thus it
>   acts like a door which receives a visitor, informs, attracts and
>   persuades him to perform an the activity and at the same time helps
>   the business achieve its goal(s).

Reference: http://graphican.com/index.php/user-experience-blog/112-landing-page-optimization

There are several other definitions of "Landing Pages" and some of them make it mandatory for a landing page to have a form. I find those definitions are too narrow and incapable to explain lateral use-cases. For example, if I only tend to educate my user about a special offer through my landing page, I would have educated him/her and achieve my objectives if the user hand landed on the page and spent next 5 seconds on it. Need of keeping of form was not there and shouldn't be there. If such a page is not called landing page, what would you call it?

**Coming to your question:**

As per the conversion rules, only ask as much infiltration which is minimally essential. Getting forms filled is our business objective and by filling forms, user doesn't achieve his/her goals. If capturing email does the job for you, keep the burden low at user and let him provide only that bit of information which is essential for you.

**However:**

If you are asking user for the email only and are looking to send information about product/service later, do consider these aspects,

- What is the risk user not reading the email and not returning to your site?
- If a user finds his/her email 5 hours later, would email have created the required engagement which would make user use that coupon?
- breaking user-flow into two stages VS in one go - is inherently less efficient. How much would you be loosing user's satisfaction by doing that?
- what alternates do you have to show user his/her discount coupon? Can you display that in browser without asking for his/her email?
- Is capturing email alone sufficient to propagate organizational objectives using other channels like email marketing?

I hope this will help you in making a decision.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong answer.

You'll notice sites like Dropbox, Facebook, and Twitter have a sign up form on their landing page (you need to log out to see this). So yes, you can put a registration form right on your landing page there's nothing odd about it as long as you keep it short and simple.

If you are worried about lengthy forms then try this
http://tympanus.net/Development/MinimalForm/

*Rule of the thumb:* capture only the essential information from the user through forms.

Comment: not sure about that miminal form, how do i go back to see the last entry? How do I assess a full form of info to check it over before pushing submit? Not sure the UX of a form like that is very good at all.

Comment: The form is only an example.

Answer (score 0):

When we get users go through forms, most important information is **valid email**. If one can allow users to go ahead and do their tasks/ achieve goals after providing an email, nothing like it.

As an alternative, you can ask them to login using Facebook or Google ID. Its a great way to cut short the time and save users to go though the forms. Some users don't prefer this thinking of getting spam posts on their account. You have to ensure it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm okay with a minimal form on a landing page - it makes the signup feel more connected to the content.

I've had situations in the past where I have had longer lead forms but still wanted to capture essential information on the landing page - like email address and name. My approach was:

-on submit of the first form the user would be directed to a thank you page that both confirmed their initial submission and provided the opportunity to provide the optional information.

-the advantage to this approach is you have the essential information even if the user bails on the longer form.

I've tested a handful of approaches and found this one to be pretty solid. It definitely beat putting a long form on the landing page and slightly edged out a button that points to a form.

Answer (score 0):

I generally have a landing page with a 'Request Invite' or some other type of button that is associated with a field to enter the email address.  Then, I fire off the email - only folks who can receive this (or find it in their spam) then come back and complete their registration.  You can also use that period to maybe survey new users or look them up on Social to discover who your Whales are.